# Choosing the right structure for noSQL database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've been developing for years with MySQL and lately working hard on noSQL.

I think about how to build a database structure for a new app, and this is how I would do this in MySQL:

**Option 1**

```
users - id, name, etc..
projects = id, name, etc..
user_projects: id, user_id,project_id,role
```

Should the noSQL DB stay same as the MySQL structure above or:

**Option 2**

```
/users - name, etc
/project: name,etc..
/user/projects: user_id,project_id, role
```

Also, what are the differenced between both structures when using noSQL database?

**Use case:** Users can login and view a list of their projects. When user access one of his projects, he can manage them (read/write). Each user can be assosicated to multiple projects. Each projects have multiple team members and each member is assigned to a role.

Comment: When modeling data for a NoSQL database, you need to model the data for the specific use-cases for your app. Without knowing those use-cases, comparing alternative models is meaningless. I highly recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: That's why I asked when it's recommended to use Option 1 and when to use Option 2

Comment: As said: without knowing those use-cases, comparing alternative models is meaningless.

Comment: Use case: Users can login and view a list of their projects. When user access one of his projects, he can manage them (read/write). Each user can be assosicated to multiple projects. Each projects have multiple team members and each member is assigned to a role.